# how can I find the sample document?

Tags: document, wso2, appserver

I have some troubles in WSO2.

1. is there any sample combining different servers together, in order to explain the mechanism of WSO2? for example, ASS and DSS, or ASS and mushup server, I find a sample of this, but without the document, like my second question.
2. in AS 5.0.0, I find some samples without notes in the README file. but get this "Please download the Documentation Distribution and refer to the Chad sample document for
   detailed instructions on how to run the Chad sample."

how can I get the detail explanation in the website?

Comment: Chad sample guide : http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS500/The+Polling+Station+Sample

Comment: check out shopping cart sample which contains several artifact types such as ESB, BPS, Data Services, Gadgets etc. http://wso2.org/project/carbon-studio/1.0.14/docs/shopping-cart-sample.html

Answer (score 1):

1. There examples are not in the official documentation, but sometime they are available in Wso2 OxygenTalk or having a look at Wso2 Developers, like:

   http://charithaka.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Data%20services

   http://kasunweranga.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/wso2-business-activity-monitor-200.html

   http://chamaras.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/enter-post-title-here.html
2. You can find the official documentation of ANY WSo2 Products on the official website, for AS for example is here: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS500/WSO2+Application+Server+Documentation

have a look at the picture to have an idea:
[image]

Comment: thank you but one thing more, do you have any idea about the shoppingcart sample? I found it not working when I try to start the DSS in eclipse. It just display the error message: Table 'bps.reg_path' doesn't exist.